# How to become administrator or root to access files when receiving "permission denied"

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, root

Just installed Ubuntu. Plugged an external drive used to store images, documents, and copies of programs. I can not access it. Says permission denied. How to fix this?

Comment: Show the commands you use.

Comment: Try to go into the directory as root and then try to change the permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I figured it out. In terminal just type "sudo nautilus". Then you can change owner permission for any folder.

Comment: You could add an entry to your `/etc/fstab` file. Verify if there is more than one partition to be mounted, and the file system (ie FAT, NTFS, ext4 etc). Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Options

Comment: That is a bit over my level for right now. But thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Root Permission SOLVED.. open a  terminal and do the following.

- 1) type "sudo nautilus"
  ( a file window will open)
- 2) go to the folder you want to change permission for.
- 3) right-click the folder
- 4) click on permission
  (a window with a list will open)
- 5) scroll to your user name and click it.
  (you now have root permission to that folder)

This is especially useful for GIMP and Inkscape when you need to add fonts, brushes, scripts, and extensions.